# Pythonic way to call a function

Tags: python

I was wondering if I could achieve something along these lines using python:

I have these 5 functions:

```
def compile_a(self):
    pass


def compile_b(self):
    pass


def compile_c(self):
    pass


def compile_d(self):
    pass


def compile_e(self):
    pass
```

and I have some function which is supposed to wrap these functions, in a sense like this:

```
def compile_by_command(self, command_type):
    if command_type == 'a':
        self.compile_a()
    elif command_type == 'b':
        self.compile_b()
    elif command_type == 'c':
        self.compile_c()
    elif command_type == 'd':
        self.compile_d()
    elif command_type == 'e':
        self.compile_e()
```

I was wondering if there is some pythonic magic which looks something like this:

```
command_pool = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

def compile_by_command(self, command_type):
    if command_type in command_pool:
        self.compile_{command_type}()
```

I mean a way to call the function using string formatting or something of that sort.

Thanks.

Comment: A map of commands to functions would be the better way of doing it.

Comment: You can  do `exec(f'self.compile_{command_type}()')`

Comment: Why not make `command_pool` a dict of command_type to function? `command_pool = {'a': compile_a, ...}`

Comment: @Sujay `exec` should be a last resort, however.

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string

Comment: Reflection magic: `getattr(self, f"compile_{command_type}")`

Comment: The non-reflection ways of doing this is by keeping a dictionary, and then `.register("a", Class.a)`.

Comment: Thanks guys, tired me did not think about it, lol.